# gpiozero: Ignore false positives/negatives

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, gpiozero

I've seen several threads where users experience some noise fluctuation in the GPIO input readings, for instance, without any physical change to a Button's state, the events when_released/when_pressed are being triggered, even with correct configuration of pull-up/pull-down.

This is normal and expected on "real world" scenarios, however I would like to know if there is a way using the `gpiozero` library, to ignore events that happen too fast, for instance, a button is **active**, then a `release` and `press` event are triggered with a small interval in between, say 10ms for instance. I nee to ignore both the `press` and `release` rather only the `release` if I configure the `bounce_time`.

Is this possible with `gpiozero`? I've been trying to understand the library code, but I haven't found a way to do this without hacking too much.

The `Button.bounce_time` property is not applicable, since that configures only the time to ignore events after a first event happened, which is not what I need. I need to ignore all events (including the first one) if another event happened really close to the first one.

BTW, I'm using `RPi.GPIO` as the pin factory for `gpiozero`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware my pigpio library is the only gpiozero back-end to have a proper debounce implementation.

pigpio provides a glitch filter which ignores any level transitions shorter than a specified number of microseconds.

E.g. from Python [set_glitch_filter()](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_glitch_filter).

Comment: Awesome joan, I will try your library and let you know if it solved.

Comment: Joan, thanks for the library. Everything working as expected. Is there any way to log everytime a glitch is ignored? Also, I have some ideas on using this library on devices other than RPi. Is there any channel you prefer we can talk some more?