# False trigger issue using GPIO input

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 and in my particular case, I am using it to sense when either a button is pressed, or power is dropped, both using the same GPIO input.

Both functions work, however, there are small glitches that trigger my shutdown circuit, like plugging into the audio jack or plugging in the HDMI, or lights in the room, looking at it etc...

I've attempted hardware fixes like a cap on the input, to no avail.

I am led to believe that I need to use the `pi.set_glitch_filter` to eliminate this issue, however I do not know how to implement it into my code..

Please have a look at what I am working with and hopefully someone here can clear this up some for me.. The particular piece in my code is "acandbutton"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append('/storage/.kodi/addons/virtual.rpi-tools/lib')

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import xbmc

powerholdPin = 24   # board pin 36
acandbuttonPin = 23     # board pin 37


def acandbutton_callback(channel):
        xbmc.executebuiltin("ShutDown")

class Main:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(acandbuttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(powerholdPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(powerholdPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(acandbuttonPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=acandbutton_callback, bouncetime=300)


    while not xbmc.abortRequested:
        xbmc.sleep(5)

class TidyUp:
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(powerholdPin)
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(acandbuttonPin)
    GPIO.cleanup([powerholdPin,acandbuttonPin])


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    Main()
    TidyUp()
```

[image: MY SCHEME]

The part on the right does everything that it needs to..
The part on the left is getting the spurious activity. It runs well if nothing else electronic is plugged in or switched, like a light in the room, or even my phone plugged into it's charger. It's that sensitive. The power to the PI is consistent and even powered when unplugged due to the UPS, although the intention is to have a clean shutdown when the wall power is either lost or due to a button press. (which both work). It's seeming to pick up on static or other micro-changes also.

Here's a link to another thread of similar issue perhaps..

[gpiozero: Ignore false positives/negatives](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66937/gpiozero-ignore-false-positives-negatives)

Comment: What power supply are you using on your Pi3 ?

Comment: Anecdotely, I've never had this problem and don't recall anyone here reporting it either, so you may want to double check, e.g., there isn't something loose in the circuit (bad solder joint etc) that is being affected by vibration.

Comment: I can't comment on the code, but you have given no detail of what is connected to the Pi. This is a high impedance circuit (relying on internal pullup). I would be looking at applying established engineering practice to minimise any interference before trying to apply a software solution.

Comment: I am using "The official and recommended universal micro USB power supply for Raspberry Pi". The spurious activity occurs regardless of the peripherals connected. Flipping a light switch in the room will activate the ShutDown sequence.

Comment: As with other commenters, I think this is a HW issue with your circuit. My guess is that your pull-up / pull-down associated with the buttons is missing or insufficient. Without details of the HW configuration, however, all we can do is guess.

Comment: What a bizarre circuit; you bias a GPIO input at 1.5V, between the ON & OFF levels, and wonder why it is unstable! This is NOT a Pi question.

Comment: From the documents that I have read, the threshold levels are 1.3v for high and 0.8v for a low. The reason for the bias is for none other than a desire for a quicker action and to keep the voltage low enough to not destroy the GPIO. The power supply which in itself can drain slow enough to not trigger until it is below 0.8v. For a few cents plus any cost of a button and a bizarre idea, I have converted a rather clumsy UPS into something that actually does what you would expect of one. If it would actually only trigger on a "low" being 0.8v or less, no issue.

Comment: Well, it seems there's little information on the actual threshold levels. Sources say the above, and others just assume something else. It's bizarre how cryptic an open device is. I've increased the bias, reading another assumption of 2.0v = high, and it's behaving correctly, aside of that it now takes about 10 seconds to actually register an AC mains loss. Not the best for my particular application. Well, there it is, a power on/off button and safe shutdown for under $30. Bizarre. I've got 2 new pico hats for sale. Warning, they dont work with LibreElec or have button power control. Bizarre

Comment: Perhaps you could try using an op-amp comparator? The output of something like an LM358 would go hard low as soon as the non-inverting input voltage falls a couple millivolts below the inverting input. Then you could just use a polling filter like the one in RPi.GPIO like crasic said to filter out the glitches.

Answer (score 3):

I think information about the circuit is more important. Because your problem does not make sense, I will edit the answer if you add more info.

This functionality is not exposed to the python library you are using. Your best and simplest option is to check the state in your callback function.

The function `pi.set_glitch_filter` is a `pigpio` function, the functionality is described in the [documentation](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)

This requires running additional software (`pigpiod` - a gpio server), which may or may not be compatible with the library you are using

**Note**: By *deglitching* I assume you mean ignoring *spurious* events, i.e. ones that are short and not "real". As opposed to *debouncing* which is when a "real" transition is followed shortly by many rapid transitions due to mechanical action.

---

Neither `pigpio`, nor `RPi.GPIO` implement a real glitch filter.

`RPi.GPIO` [runs a polling loop](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/event_gpio.c#l324), and therefore there is an inherent glitch filter in that events shorter than the poll time (probably a few ms, but haven't checked) are never detected.

`pigpio` is a socket based protocol, and the 'glitch' fliter enabled with [`pi.set_glitch_filter`](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_glitch_filter) is software filtering.

> This filter affects the GPIO samples returned to callbacks set up with callback and wait_for_edge.
>
> It does not affect levels read by read, read_bank_1, or read_bank_2.

Switching to callbacks using `pigpgio` may be sufficient, even if it is software deglitching.

Real Hardware deglitching exists, but is poorly documented in Raspberry Pi. This is deglitching done on the clock cycle level (e.g. signal must be stable 2 PIO clocks before latching), configured directly via registers,  and is used in hardware drivers and kernel side interrupt handlers. This is means interrupts as fast as possible while filtering many spurious events.

Answer (score 1):

I use falling edge to reboot. Pin 11 and gnd.

> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>
> import os
>
> channel=11
>
> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
>
> GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
>
> GPIO.wait_for_edge(channel, GPIO.FALLING)
>
> os.system("sudo reboot")

Answer (score 0):

My rain bucket was getting false triggers. It has a relatively long duration trigger so I just checked to see if the pin really went low.

```
def countRain(rainPin):
    global totalRain
    global currentRain

    if (GPIO.input(rainPin) == False) :
        totalRain += .012
        currentRain += .012
   
GPIO.add_event_detect(rainPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=countRain, bouncetime=100)
```